# Trying to find a book about reincarnation I read in the early 90s

Tags: story-identification, novel, reincarnation

I am trying to find a book about a woman who is having flashbacks to her previous lives. In one flashback she is a cave-woman who is about to get married too young. Someone takes her maidenhood and the elders throw her off the cliff since she is no longer pure.

In the present day she is attacked by muggers and finds strength she didn't know she had.

I can't remember the rest of the book. I thought the title was *Fury* or *The Fury* but all of my searches turn up empty. I read this book in the early 90's, Around 1993 or 1994. It would be older but I have no idea of the author.

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=The+Fury&type=Fiction+Titles

Answer (score 2):

*[Fury](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/john-coyne-4/fury-6/)* by John Coyne, published in 1989.

Summary review (with bolding by me):

> After a thriller (The Hunting Season, 1987) and a saga (Brothers and Sisters, 1986), Coyne returns to the horror genre that launched his career, but the unusual premise here--a woman learns that she's the **reincarnation** of the first human--is overwhelmed by the same excessive pornoviolence that marred The Searing. The Piercing, and Hobgoblin. Jennifer Winters, a bright and pretty Manhattan lawyer, is the very model of a yuppie heroine--but for one problem: every now and then she turns into a superstrong maniac who bare-handedly kills people who are annoying her. It started the day she traded stares with famed New Age channeler Kathy Dart; ever since then. it's been Death Wish V, with Jennifer uncontrollably crushing and ripping up the **muggers** (and one lech) who have the unhappy knack of preying on her. Hardheaded lover Tom proves no comfort to the distraught woman: neither does channeler Phoebe Fisher, who subtly warns distraught Jennifer away from Kathy and who leads her to see that she's channeling a past self--a self who, a bit later, Kathy Dart explains is an **ice Age being**. Meanwhile, in brief interchapters overripe with sex and violence and set progressively farther in the past, we read of: an incestuous brother and sister; a 19th-century Chinese girl and her murder: a black American slave and her would-be rapist; homosexual medieval nuns; homosexual Ancient Greeks; an Ancient Egyptian woman; and cave people indulging in rape and murder. When Jennifer at last heads out to Kathy's Midwest healing center and undergoes hypnotic regression, she relives the lives we've read about and realizes that the murderous self possessing her has come to avenge an ancient wrong--leading to a last killing that destroys the unexpected villain and leaves Jennifer at peace. Coyne swaddles all this in New-Ageisms (""the nature of your existence is a reality of the mind,"" etc.). But the blood and lust still soak through: a tart enough tale, then, but tasting distinctly of pulp.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, don't forget to click on the checkmark by the voting buttons. Found by searching for *book the fury reincarnation*.